# Est-il correct de dire « Merci chéri »?

Tags: expressions, usage

Est-il correct de dire « Merci chéri »?

Ou doit-on dire « merci mon cher »?

Peut-on dire « Merci cher »?

Answer (score 3):

***Merci chéri*** et ***merci chérie*** sont grammaticalement corrects.

***Merci, cher/chère*** ne sont pas vraiment idiomatiques (en France) sauf si une précision suit : *Merci cher monsieur*, *merci chers collègues*. La forme reste cependant assez rare.

Dans un registre très soutenu, on peut utiliser ***merci mon cher*** et ***merci ma chère***.

Attention, *cher/chère* à un spectre d'utilisation beaucoup plus large que *chéri(e)* :

**Cher** : *dear* (peut être dit à tout le monde)
**Chéri** : *honey* (se dit entre époux, fiancés, petits-amis, à ses enfants ou petits-enfants, etc., très rarement en dehors du cadre familial).

Comment: Merci chéri :-)

Comment: ROTFL ;-)  Maybe should I state somewhere that my preferred pronoun is *chéri* (or not?).

Comment: Haha peut-etre chéri

Comment: Et dans la lange courant on ne dit pas "merci cher"? Parce que je crois que je l'ai entendu déja.

Comment: Non, *merci cher* n'est pas du tout une expression de la langue courante, ou alors ça peut avoir été dit par plaisanterie.

Comment: @Cantor Attention, je te vois écrire "merci chéri" dans les commentaires des réponses, au début je pensais que tu plaisantais mais j'ai l'impression que non. Tu ne peux dire ça qu'à deux types de personnes : 1) ta compagne / femme / fiancée ; 2) tes enfants. Tu ne peux même pas le dire à tes frères et soeurs, ni à tes parents, ni à tes amis, et encore moins à des inconnus sur Internet. Même en tant que plaisanterie c'est assez délicat à utiliser.

Comment: Bien « (merci) cher/chère » a été ou est toujours bien idiomatique au Qc il me semble, c'est le genre de truc que ma tante me dirait, c'est familier/populaire et possiblement vieux.

Answer (score 0):

Oui, merci chéri est correct, mais comme dit plus haut est à réserver à un cadre intime ou familial.

Un point supplémentaire toutefois : il me semble que l'expression a un peu vieilli et que si le cinéma représente bien l'évolution de la langue, l'occurrence cinématographique du mot chéri entre amants est devenue rarissime. Une autre difficulté d'emploi est liée à l'accord de l'adjectif chéri(e). Dans un film français classique, on entend Yves Montand s'adresser à sa femme (ou une personne de statut proche) avec les mots "mon chéri", accord à l'anglaise peut-être.

Answer (score -2):

Il est correct de dire « Merci chéri/chérie » ou encore « Merci mon chéri/ma chérie ». « Cher/chère » tout seul ne se dit pas  (« Merci cher. », « Merci mon cher. »), voir [ngram1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Merci+cher.&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=), [ngram2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Merci+mon+cher%3B&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=). Ce que l'on peut dire c'est « (mon) cher/(ma) chère »  suivi par une virgule et en enchainant une idée.

Les constructions de cette sorte sont appelées des appellations, et de nos jours certaines de ces appellations ont tendance à être de moins en moins utilisées dans la langue parlée du fait d'une certaine hauteur de sentiment qu'elles communiquent, sentiments que les gens ont de moins en moins les uns envers les autres ou dont ils ne souhaitent pas qu'ils transparaissent dans leur élocution orale, et donc qu'ils relèguent plutôt à la langue écrite. De plus, il sera assez rare, bien que correct d'entendre « merci, mon cher, … » ;  « Merci, cher, … » ne se dit pas. Comparativement courant sera une formule dans laquelle « (mon) cher » modifie un nom.

- Merci, cher Paul, ça vient à point …
- Merci, (mon) cher ami, mais  …
- Merci, (mon) cher monsieur, vos conseils sont utiles.
- Merci, (mon) cher collègue …
- Merci, (ma) chère enfant (haute société)

Il va sans dire que tout ce qui est appliqué à « mon » l'est aussi à « ma ».

On peut le plus souvent inverser l'ordre.

- (Mon) cher ami, merci, mais  …
- (Mon) cher monsieur, merci, vos conseils sont utiles.

Pour terminer, j'ajouterais que dans de telles appellations, la personne qui est apparemment considérée comme chère d'après les termes de l'énoncé peut ne pas être chère du tout à celui ou à celle qui parle et n'être qu'en proie au mépris de celle-ci. Un exemple typique tiré de la littérature, mais dans lequel on trouve le mot « bon » à la place de « cher », montre cela ; « cher » ne changerait pas beaucoup le sens.

- Le Renard s’en saisit, et dit : « Mon bon Monsieur,
  Apprenez que tout flatteur
  Vit aux dépens de celui qui l’écoute : […] (*Fables de Jean de La Fontaine, Le Corbeau et le Renard*)

Le lien suivant apporte des notions supplémentaires : « https://parlez-vous-french.com/utiliser-cher-cheri-francais/ ».

Comment: Merci chéri. Est-il correct dire sans le adjectif possessif? "Merci cher ami" par exemple ou on doit dire "Merci mon cher ami".

Comment: @Cantor Non, on peut dire « Merci mon cher ami. », mais c'est une forme qui fait parti d'une culture qui se perd ou qui n'a jamais été celle des classes sociales du bas de l'échelle. Le lien que je fournis a certaines choses à dire à propos de l'usage ; je vous conseille d'en acquérir un aperçu.