# La suppression de l'adjectif possessif en langage très familier avec l'adjectif « cher, chère » de Littré, que lui est-il arrivé ?

Tags: usage, adjectifs, lexique, possessif

Il n'est pas inhabituel d'avoir l'ellipse du nom ou la [substantivation](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cher) de *cher* dans une locution comme [*mon cher, ma chère*](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/cher/15125?q=cher#14988). D'autre part il y a plus d'une siècle, Littré écrivait :

> Aujourd'hui, dans le langage très familier, on supprime même
>   l'adjectif possessif. Bonjour, chers. Çà va bien, très chers ?
>   Venez-vous, chers bons ? (Dictionnaire Littré, [*cher*](https://www.littre.org/definition/cher))

D'autre part au Québec on aurait un [emploi particulier](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/40045/19187) de *cher, chère*, sans adjectif possessif ni nom qui ne l'accompagne :

> Comment vas-tu, chère/cher ?
>   Cher/chère, pourrais-tu stp. me passer le beurre ?

- Le propos de Littré est-il exact et sait-on ce qui expliquerait que
  cet emploi ait [disparu](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/39988/19187) au cours du 20<sup>e</sup> siècle ?
- Posant pour les fins de la réflexion que l'emploi québécois est un phénomène similaire à celui décrit par Littré, sait-on si c'est simplement l'ajout de l'adjectif possessif qui rend l'emploi du Québec plus usuel en français métropolitain ou devrait-on de surcroît employer un autre mot que *cher, chère* pour un contexte plus spécifique où le locuteur s'adresse à un membre plus jeune de sa famille, à un enfant (voir autre [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/40045/19187)) par exemple ; en d'autres termes qu'est-ce qui s'est substitué à cet emploi du passé généralement et spécifiquement pour la familiarité en contexte familial/inter-générationnel (ou l'évoquant) ?

Comment: Tout ce que je peux dire c'est que "très cher" est effectivement une formule assez connue, mais qui sonne vraiment vieillot ou nobliau.

Comment: Je ne pense pas que ce soit la cause de la suppression du possessif maintenant "***mon** cher **mon**sieur, **ma** chère **ma**dame*... ça fait limite pléonastique non ?

Comment: Je dis peut-être une bêtise mais, en ce qui concerne le Québec (et dans une certaine mesure la France), il faut souvent regarder ce qui se passe du côté anglophone, ici avec "dear".

Comment: Je suis assez d'accord avec Jacques, cher/chère seul est peu employé en France par exemple.

Comment: "Très cher, voudriez-vous blablabla" s'utilise aussi pour exagérer humouristiquement le respect (au moins en ile-de-france)